# Converting Apache rewrites to Nginx

Tags: apache, .htaccess, nginx, url-rewriting

I am very novice when it comes to this sort of stuff, but I am trying to port a website from Apache to Nginx because we would like to take advantage of some of Nginx's features. I am however very stumped on how to port over this rewrite. No converter or any amount of googling has helped me.

```
    <Directory "/web/matrix/rest">
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^([\w\s~=<>;!@#$%\^&\*",()-]+)((/([\w\s~=<>;!@#$%\^&\*",()-]+)/([\w\s~=<>;!@#$%\^&\*",()-]+))*)(/?)$ $2$6rest.php#?dataSource=$1 [QSA]
    RewriteRule ^/?([\w\s~=<>;!@#$%\^&\*",()-]+)/([\w\s~=<>;!@#$%\^&\*",()-]+)((/([\w\s~=<>;!@#$%\^&\*",()-]+)/([\w\s~=<>;!@#$%\^&\*",()-]+))*)(/?)rest.* $3$7rest.php?$1=$2 [QSA,N]
    RewriteRule ^/rest.php rest.php [QSA,L]
    </Directory>
```

Comment: What do you precisely wanto to do? What have you tried?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am not sure exactly what it does, but I know that we can't get past the login page of our website without it. I wasn't sure if what I provided was enough information to create a translation or not. I have tried things like the following, it may be silly as I am not quite sure what I am doing

Comment: I guess I am not quite sure how to post it in a comment, this is my first day on this site.